# Will an HResult from an exception always be non-zero?

Tags: .net, exception

Will the `HResult` property of an exception raised by .NET always have a non-zero value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. HResult = zero is

> S_OK  Operation successful    0x00000000

General HResult info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa378137.aspx

HResults mapped to exceptions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Each exception is mapped to a distinct HRESULT

... a strong indicator that they would always be non-zero.

However, these can be set via code as well ([Map HRESULTS to Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1(v=vs.110).aspx)), so I tend to think it'd be one of those cases where "better to not assume it will always be nonzero, even though it practically is always nonzero:

> User-defined exception classes can specify whatever HRESULT is appropriate. These exception classes can dynamically change the HRESULT to be returned when the exception is generated by setting the HResult field on the exception object.